# How to use custom buttons in FullCalendar 4.2 with built in method using JavaScript version?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am having issues creating a custom button that will fire the prevYear or prev methods.  The reason being i only want to load events for the currently displayed month without have to have all the data from the table stored in memory.

I have read over the documentation on fullcalendar.io site.  I have also been googling for anyone that has tried this and the one that came close didn't work.  Which was using javascript to capture the onclick and then have it do something.

```
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: ['bootstrap', 'interaction', 'timeGrid', 'dayGrid', 'list'],
        header: {
            left: 'myCustomButton,prev,next,nextYear today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,listWeek'
        },
        customButtons: {
            myCustomButton: {
                text: 'Prev Year',
                click: function (calendar) {
                    calendar.prevYear();
                }
            }
        },
        businessHours: {
            daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            startTime: '05:00',
            endTime: '18:00'
        },
        defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        droppable: true,
        dateClick: function (info) {
            //let popupDayLabel = document.getElementById('aemLabel');
            //popupDayLabel.innerHTML(info.dateStr + ' Events');
            OnDateClick(info);
        }
    })

    calendar.render();
```

What i am hoping for is to be able to either intercept and add to the built in prev/prevYear/next/nextYear functions or custom to trigger the built in navigation along with triggering ajax to pull in only the events for the month being displayed without having to have the whole table loaded in memory.

Comment: " i only want to load events for the currently displayed month" ...fullCalendar has already solved this problem for you, without the need for custom buttons to capture prev/next clicks (which, it should be noted, are [not the only ways](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-navigation) for the date to be changed, anyway).

Comment: You haven't shown how you're adding events to the calendar, but the recommended way is using either [a JSON feed](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) or a [custom function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function). In both of these cases, you are giving fullCalendar a dynamic event source. It will, whenever the dates change to a new range, automatically request new events from the source you provide. It will give the event source start and end date parameters so that the source can filter the data it returns to just the relevant events for those dates.

Comment: ADyson,  It appears i miss read the documentation when i originally looked it over or i missed a section all together.  I have had a chance to look over that section and i see what your are saying and will make adjustments to my API.  Thank you for pointing that out to me.